# How do I disable IPv4-mapped IPv6?

Tags: linux, ipv6

On my Linux box, I have various daemons which can bind to all IPv6-enabled interfaces on `::`. When they do so, Linux sends IPv4 requests to that daemon mapped as, for instance, `::ffff:198.51.100.37`.

I would instead like IPv4 connections to be refused and only IPv6 connections accepted when a daemon binds to `::`. To receive IPv4 connections, I want the daemon to have to explicitly bind to `0.0.0.0` (as well as `::`).

In other words, I want to run a service exclusively on IPv6, and not on IPv4.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is controlled by the `net.ipv6.bindv6only` sysctl. Add the following to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and run `sudo sysctl -p` to effect the change.

```
net.ipv6.bindv6only=1
```

Applications can also explicitly only bind to the IPv6 address instead of changing this globally, for example, nginx has the `ipv6only` option to the [`listen`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen) directive. This corresponds to the [`IPV6_V6ONLY`](http://wiki.treck.com/setsockopt#IPv6_Level_Options) option to `setsockopt()`.

Comment: Fortunately I found that the app (in this case, OpenSSH) was already setting IPV6_V6ONLY on the socket when I set `ListenAddress ::` so I didn't need to resort to using the sysctl (and reconfiguring everything else).